# JTextField more as one row and start the text at the top of the text field

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

how can I implement a TextField which has more than one and starts at the top of the TextField?
If I just implement a JTextField the coursor or the text of the field is always in the middle and does not start at the top

Comment: For example in this comment field the text I´m writing starts in the first row and so at the top of this comment field. If the line is full i can write in the next line. But my JTextField has only one line and this line is in the middle of the field. I want to get more lines

Comment: If you want to use a simple Swing text component that has more lines, don't use a JTextField. Use a JTextArea instead.

Comment: Thanks. Now it works. Do you also know, how to implement that the text automatically switches to the next line, if the first line is full?

Comment: A little secret: Google can help you search this and other sites. For example please check this Google Search on these key words: [how to make a jtextarea wrap text site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+make+a+jtextarea+wrap+text+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 3):

> JTextField is a lightweight component that allows the editing of a single line of text.

([API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html))

You seem to want a UI component that supports multiple lines of text; that would be `JTextArea`, not `JTextField`.